# Why does one of these htaccess directives remove the query string and the other does not?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am struggling to figure out why one of these htaccess directives removes the query string and the other does not.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=invitations
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /Invitations? [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=corporate_invitations
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /Invitations/Corporate? [L,R=301,QSD]
```

The first will redirect from a URL like **/index.php?l=page_view&p=invitations** and correctly rewrite to **/Invitations**.

The second, if you navigate to **/index.php?l=page_view&p=corporate_invitations** you will be redirected to **/Invitations/Corporate?l=page_view&p=corporate_invitations**.  So my question is why does the first remove the query string and the second does not.

--Edit--

Since I am on Apache 2.4.12 I removed the ? at the end since QSD is working correctly for the other lines.  I have added more rules and the only one that fails to remove the query string is the Invitations/Corporate.  It does redirect but leaves the query string in place.  I thought it might be the / in the middle of the rule but Invitations/Party is working correctly.

The entire .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=corporate_invitations
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /Invitations/Corporate [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=invitations
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /Invitations [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=message_in_a_bottle_gifts
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /GiftBottles [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=party_invitations
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /Invitations/Party [L,R=301,QSD]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: QSD seems to apply only to Apache 2.4 and above. What do you run? See https://www.philipphoffmann.de/blog/2012/08/16/how-to-discard-the-query-string-in-a-rewriterule-apache-mod_rewrite/

Comment: Both shoud works the same way, check your rewrite logs, check if you dont have extra space or special chars in your flags [L,R=301,QSD]

Comment: @JayMcTee - Apache/2.4.12

Comment: I have added several new lines and all of them are working except for the corporate invites one.  I copied a working line and recreated the corporate one and it still fails to remove the query strings.  Since I am on Apache 2.4 I did remove the ? since QSD seems to be doing the job for the others.  Having trouble getting rewrite logs to work correctly.  Have edited the virtualhost.conf file to add 'LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3'.  Not sure where this is supposed to write the log however...  See edit above.

Comment: If you want to see it in action check: http://a-m-o-r.com/index.php?l=page_view&p=corporate_invitations and http://a-m-o-r.com/index.php?l=page_view&p=party_invitations

Comment: I have the logging working now and I have analyzed the difference between the Party and Corporate redirects and there is no difference.  I set the log level at "LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8".  Possible bug in Apache?

Comment: Updated to Apache/2.4.16 no fix.